# Code bugs in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

What are the disadvantages of  this code :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Learn;Integrated Security=True";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tblUser(name,family,tel)Values('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtFamily.Text + "','" + txtTel.Text + "')";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Bugs and disadvantages are not the same thing. Does this code fail to do what you want?  Why are you asking about the disadvantages of this particular piece of code? We need more information in order to answer this well.

Comment: What do YOU think some disadvantages are? I'm assuming you have some concerns if you've written it.

Answer (score 4):

You mean besides the fact that the SqlConnection won't be disposed, and that the SqlCommand is written in such a way as to invite a SQL Injection attack?

Relevant XKCD comic:

http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: A nitpick: The connection will be disposed except when there's an exception. The OP should definitely be wrapping the connection and command in `using` blocks though.

Comment: The tag says `winforms`, so SQL injection isn't much of an attack. If the WinForms app can access the database, the user can already execute any SQL they want against the database.

Comment: @gabe You still need to consider the potential of SQL injection attacks from within your authorized users. It can be used maliciously to destroy data, or to elevate access and see info they shouldn't be allowed to. Just because it is informs doesn't mean they have the authority to drop tables in the db.

Comment: Robaticus: I'm not saying that SQL injection isn't a concern; it's just not really an attack. The user running this program *already* has access to the DB. They could open up the EXE in a hex editor, copy the connection string out, paste it into their favorite SQL Manager, and be able to execute any SQL they want against the DB.

Comment: @Gabe - I hear ya. I think we can all agree that it's still an essential practice to sanitize inputs like that when you're passing them into a SQL command string. Though, really, preparing an unparamaterized text command and executing that against your database is rarely a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

One major disadvantage is that you don't quote your strings or use parameterized queries, so somebody who inputs `O'Brien` for their last name will get an exception.

Of course, that also means that somebody can enter arbitrary SQL into a text box and have you execute it for them. That's bad.

Answer (score 0):

Related to secure coding....

Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks since you are directly using txtName.text in the code to form a query. Parameterized queries should be used. Additionally, you should validate the txtName.txt before using it. That is it.

Comment: What does it mean to "validate the txtName.txt"? Are you suggesting that there are some invalid values?

Comment: Well.. `'); DROP TABLE tblUser; --` would be an invalid value - although it wouldn't hurt anything if parameterized queries were used.

Comment: @Joel: Why shouldn't that be a valid name? If that's the name Bobby was given, a user should be allowed to enter it into a database and store it there.